# How to find object inside array inside object

Tags: arrays, object, target

Pardon my confusion but how can I get the value of the **name** key nested inside this object:

```
{
    "id":"5SA72165CP580074WLPMNIYA",
    "transactions":[{
        "amount":{
            "total":"23.80",
        },
        "item_list":{
            "items":[{
                "name":"Gateway", // THIS!
            }]
        },
        "related_resources":[{
            "sale":{
                "id":"1PD13091HH4593923",
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

I am trying to get it like this:

```
console.log(transactions[item_list.items[name]])
```

and it's returning *undefined*

Comment: Can you post your code as well ?

Comment: Hi! The console.log is all the code I need to clarify this. I have posted an answer but it only works if the index of the properties remains the same.

Comment: So you are saying this thing could be dynamic and you just need to get value with key as name right ?

Comment: yes it's dynamic. I need to get the the value "Gateway".

Comment: Got it, let me try something , you need to write a code logic for this.

Comment: Are you sure? i know for a fact the "keys" of these properties (amount, item_list, related_resources) will not change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182829/discussion-between-zenwraight-and-joao-alves-marrucho).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like this

```
let dynamicContent = {
    "id":"5SA72165CP580074WLPMNIYA",
    "transactions":[{
        "amount":{
            "total":"23.80",
        },
        "item_list":{
            "items":[{
                "name":"Gateway", // THIS!
            }]
        },
        "related_resources":[{
            "sale":{
                "id":"1PD13091HH4593923",
            }
        }]
    }]
};

dynamicContent.transactions.forEach(function(itemList) {
  itemList.item_list.items.forEach(function(element){
    if(element.hasOwnProperty("name")) {
      console.log(element["name"]);
    }
  });
});
```

I am basically iterating over the array part. 
You can play around with the above logic to get what you want.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the properties will not change, you can dive in it by index:

```
console.log(transactions[0].item_list.items[0].name)
```